# Discrete Math Inclusive or VS Exclusive or

Tags: analysis, discrete-mathematics, logic

### Question:

Are *inclusive or*  and *exclusive or* both considered *dis-junction* ?

### My own thinking:

I believe yes, because both inclusive and exclusive or are using or. They just happen to have different symbols.

### Reference:

- Inclusive or: To be true, at-least one or both statements are true. Else, false.
- Exclusive or: To be True, Only one statement of p, q can true. Else, false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course they are. Both are meant for distinguishing between two alternatives (from here dis-junction). Since they behave differently, it is necessary to add 'inclusive' or 'exclusive' qualification.

Comment: Exactly that is what I thought, thanks for confirming.